# Scrapy: Google Crawl doesn't work

Tags: scrapy

When I try to crawl Google for search results, Scrapy just yields the Google home page:
http://pastebin.com/FUbvbhN4

Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy

class GoogleFinanceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google"
    start_urls = ['http://www.google.com/#q=finance.google.com:+3m+co']
    allowed_domains = ['www.google.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Is there something wrong with this url as a starting url? When I open it in my browser -- by putting it in the address bar (not by filling in the search form) -- I get valid search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, looks like that address is redirecting to the home page:

example with `scrapy shell http://www.google.com/#q=finance.google.com:+3m+co`:

```
...
[s]   request    <GET http://www.google.com/#q=finance.google.com:+3m+co>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.google.com/>
...
```

Checking your url it makes sense, it isn't containing parameters, but `#q` (which isn't a url parameter) and the browser is the one recognizing that and making it a google search, so it is not exactly a url path.

the correct google search url is: `http://www.google.com/search?q=YOURQUERY`

Comment: Ah, yes. This is because Chrome is Google-aware. When I try that in Safari, it does the same thing (redirects to Google homepage).

Answer (score 2):

for the most cases, google would redirect the spider to the CAPTCHA page, bing search result is easier to crawl.

there is a project for crawling search result from Google/Bing/Baidu https://github.com/titantse/seCrawler