# Python 2.7 BeautifulSoup4 is returning an empty set

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the links from a google search with bs4 but my code is returning an empty set.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website = "https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=science"

response=requests.get(website)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

link_info = soup.find_all("h3", {class": "r"})
print link_info
```

The `<h3 class="r">` is where the links for all the results are not just the link for the first result.

In response I get `[]` and this is for any other class I try to request including `<div class="rc">`.

Here is a prt sc of what I am after,

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy: Google Crawl doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395133/scrapy-google-crawl-doesnt-work)

Comment: The query is POST request, not GET. You should use POST request and put q in post params as mentioned below. To understand it better, open inspect element in the browser, open network tab and then send the request. You will see a list of URL hits being done there. Click on one of them and you will see a more about your requests. There will be options like params, headers, cookies. Params are the post parameters sent to the server. If it is GET request then, usually there won't be any params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following code

```
url = 'http://www.google.com/search?'
params = {'q': 'science'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
link_info = soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "r"})
print link_info
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```py
# select container with needed elements and grab each element in a loop
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):

  # grabs each <a> tag from the container and then grabs an href attribute
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Code from [Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41258567/15164646) will throw an error because there's no such `r` `CSS` selector. It's changed.

---

Make sure you're using `user-agent` because default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and you'll receive a different HTML with some sort of an error. User-agent fakes user visit by adding this information into [HTTP request headers](https://serpapi.com/organic-results).

I wrote a dedicated blog about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines that cover multiple solutions](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

Pass `user-agent` in request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc')[:5]:
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

  print(link, sep='\n')

--------
'''
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
https://www.reddit.com/r/NewTubers/comments/47hw1g/what_does_katana_mean_it_means_japanese_sword_2/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0130236/characters/nm0360481
http://www.subzin.com/quotes/Samurai+Cop/What+does+Katana+mean%3F+-+It+means+Japanese+sword
'''
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with selecting correct selectors or figuring out why certain things don't work as expected and then maintain it over time. Instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the date you want fast.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"][:5]:
  print(result['link'])

--------
'''
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
https://www.reddit.com/r/NewTubers/comments/47hw1g/what_does_katana_mean_it_means_japanese_sword_2/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0130236/characters/nm0360481
http://www.subzin.com/quotes/Samurai+Cop/What+does+Katana+mean%3F+-+It+means+Japanese+sword
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.